# Unable to persist the checked checkboxes when item is searched by SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a RecylerView which has SearchView widget and list of items containing checkbox and player names. There is no problem when I scroll items and select items checkboxes are selected. But problem arises when ever I search items by there name and then select them, when I try to search another item the previously item gets unchecked.

When i type BAT and list of player with bat are shown then i selected 2 players
[image]

Then I remove BAT from searchview and you can see both 2 selected players get deselected
[image]

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ArrayList<SomeObject> someObjects= new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> id=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> role= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> price= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> teamName= new ArrayList<>();
CheckBox chk;
int totc=0;
int batc=0;
int maxbat=3;
int bwlc=0;
int maxbal=3;
int allc=0;
int maxall=4;
ValueFilter valueFilter;
int wktc=0;
int maxwkt=1;

Context c;
ArrayList<PlayersPool> players;
ArrayList<PlayersPool> checkdata;
ArrayList<PlayersPool> searchdata;


LayoutInflater inflater;
boolean[] itemChecked;



public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PlayersPool> players) {
    this.c = c;
    this.players = players;

    searchdata=players;
    itemChecked= new boolean[players.size()];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return players.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return players.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
     return players.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater==null){

        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,null);
    }

    final TextView nameP= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameP);
    TextView priceP= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceP);
    final TextView roleP= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roleP);
    final TextView team= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_name);
    chk= (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    chk.setFocusable(false);

    nameP.setText(players.get(position).getName());
    priceP.setText(players.get(position).getPrice());
    roleP.setText(players.get(position).getRole());
    team.setText(players.get(position).getTeamName());

    if (players.get(position).isselected) {
        chk.setChecked(true);

    } else {
        chk.setChecked(false);
    }

    checkdata= new ArrayList<>();


    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {

            if(b) {
                players.get(position).isselected = true;

                if (players.get(position).getRole().equals("BAT")) {
                   Toast.makeText(c,"Checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    batc++;

                    if (batc > 3) {
                        batc--;
                        totc--;
                        chk.setChecked(false);
                        players.get(position).isselected = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                players.get(position).isselected = false;

                if(players.get(position).getRole().equals("BAT")){

                    batc--;
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<PlayersPool> filterList = new ArrayList<PlayersPool>();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchdata.size(); i++) {

                if ((searchdata.get(i).getRole().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    final PlayersPool play = new PlayersPool();

                    play.setName(searchdata.get(i).getName());
                    play.setTeamName(searchdata.get(i).getTeamName());
                    play.setRole(searchdata.get(i).getRole());
                    play.setPrice(searchdata.get(i).getPrice());
                    play.setIsselected(searchdata.get(i).isselected);



                    filterList.add(play);



                }


            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = searchdata.size();
            results.values = searchdata;
        }
        return results;

    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        players = (ArrayList<PlayersPool>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use loop for this.

```
    if (players.get(position).isselected) {
        chk.setChecked(true);

        for(PlayersPool item: searchdata){
            if(players.get(position).getName().equals(item.getName())){
                item.setIsselected(true);
            }
        }

    } else {
        chk.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot it solved my problem. As i forgot to add loop.

Comment: Yes, for loop required for this.